# Is it ever ok to use a stateful default instance of a VBA custom class?

Tags: vba

I'm developing some finance-related Excel add-ins for use by a small group within the commercial team at my work.

I want to create a persistent object that stores state for specific metadata values related to the app, so that code in any class or standard module has access to them, and so that I only need to state them once or set their defaults at application startup. Examples include:

- the App's name
- release/version numbers
- top-level registry key to store/retrieve settings
- "First Run" status
- is logging enabled

In the past I would have declared global constants for these things, but I'm trying to approach this using a more current pattern (if there is one).

My thoughts are to create a class with the `PredeclaredID` attribute set to true, and to populate the default values on workbook load and/or class initialisation events.

I'm aware that it's not considered good practice to maintain state in a default instance of a class but I can't think of another way to create a persistent object. I know a little bit about factory patterns and would be happy to use one but the persistency thing is tripping me up.

Any insights or alternative approaches appreciated.

---

### Update 10 Jun 2020

I've had some success with this approach.
Here's the prototype I've been working on, incorporating freeflow's helpful suggestion.

**Class attributes and property procedures**

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "AppSettings"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Attribute VB_Description = "Persistent object that exposes app-specific settings to other procedures and objects"
'@Folder "MyAddin.02 AddIn"
'@ModuleDescription ("Persistent object that exposes app-specific settings to other procedures and objects")
'@PredeclaredId
Option Explicit

Private Type TAppSettings
    Name As String
    LoggingEnabled As Boolean
    Author As String
    AuthorEmail As String
    ReleaseName As String
    Version As String
    TopLevelRegKey As String
    AppFirstRun As Boolean
    LogPath As String
End Type

Private this As TAppSettings

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = this.Name
End Property

Public Property Get LoggingEnabled() As Boolean
    LoggingEnabled = this.LoggingEnabled
End Property

Public Property Let LoggingEnabled(ByVal value As Boolean)
    this.LoggingEnabled = value
End Property

Public Property Get Author() As String
    Author = this.Author
End Property

Public Property Get AuthorEmail() As String
    AuthorEmail = this.AuthorEmail
End Property

Public Property Get ReleaseName() As String
    ReleaseName = this.ReleaseName
End Property

Public Property Get Version() As String
    Version = this.Version
End Property

Public Property Get TopLevelRegKey() As String
    TopLevelRegKey = this.TopLevelRegKey
End Property

Public Property Get AppFirstRun() As Boolean
    AppFirstRun = this.AppFirstRun
End Property

Public Property Let AppFirstRun(ByVal value As Boolean)
    this.AppFirstRun = value
End Property
```

**The bootstrapper**: This procedure passes default values for the application to the Populate method and gets called from the class `Initialize` event. The attributes are hard-coded here as constants but could be sourced from workbook custom properties or an external settings file.

```
'@Description "Sets properties of default AppSettings object. Called by class initialise event"
Private Sub BootStrapper()

    Const APP_NAME As String = "MyTestApp"
    Const APP_AUTHOR As String = "John Smith"
    Const APP_AUTHOR_EMAIL As String = "john.smith@hightower.com"
    Const APP_RELEASE_NAME As String = "R1"
    Const APP_VERSION As String = "V1.0"
    Const APP_FIRSTRUN_DEFAULT As Boolean = True
    Const APP_LOGGING_DEFAULT As Boolean = False

    Dim success As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    success = Me.Populate( _
              Author:=APP_AUTHOR, _
              AuthorEmail:=APP_AUTHOR_EMAIL, _
              Name:=APP_NAME, _
              ReleaseName:=APP_RELEASE_NAME, _
              Version:=APP_VERSION, _
              AppFirstRunDefault:=APP_FIRSTRUN_DEFAULT, _
              AppLoggingDefault:=APP_LOGGING_DEFAULT)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not success Then
    Err.Raise _
        vbObjectError + 1024, _
        "AppSettings.Bootstrapper", _
        "Failed to bootstrap the static AppSettings class"
    End If

End Sub
```

**The Populate method**: Sets the class attributes, creates a top-level registry key, and reads/stores settings for the read/write attributes in the registry.

```
'@Description "Populates AppSettings object properties"
Friend Function Populate( _
       ByVal Author As String, _
       ByVal AuthorEmail As String, _
       ByVal Name As String, _
       ByVal ReleaseName As String, _
       ByVal Version As String, _
       ByVal AppFirstRunDefault As Boolean, _
       ByVal AppLoggingDefault As Boolean) As Boolean

    Populate = False
    On Error Resume Next                         'Handle any errors by function return value

    ' Populate properties for those values passed in to the function
    With this
        .Author = Author
        .AuthorEmail = AuthorEmail
        .Name = Name
        .ReleaseName = ReleaseName
        .Version = Version
        .TopLevelRegKey = .ReleaseName & "\" & .Version
    End With

    ' Populate the AppFirstRun and LoggingEnabled settings from the registry
    ' If registry settings don't exist then this is the true first run so set defaults
    Dim registryValue As String
    With this
        registryValue = GetSetting(.Name, .TopLevelRegKey, "AppFirstRun", vbNullString)
        If registryValue = vbNullString Then     'Set default if no registry value
            .AppFirstRun = AppFirstRunDefault
            SaveSetting .Name, .TopLevelRegKey, "AppFirstRun", CStr(AppFirstRunDefault)
        Else
            .AppFirstRun = CBool(registryValue)
        End If
        registryValue = GetSetting(.Name, .TopLevelRegKey, "LoggingEnabled", vbNullString)
        If registryValue = vbNullString Then     'Set default if no registry value
            .LoggingEnabled = AppLoggingDefault
            SaveSetting .Name, .TopLevelRegKey, "LoggingEnabled", CStr(AppLoggingDefault)
        Else
            .LoggingEnabled = CBool(registryValue)
        End If
    End With

    If Err.Number = 0 Then Populate = True
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

**The Initialise procedure**: The `Class_Initialize` code checks that the caller isn't trying to New up another instance of the class, and if not, calls the bootstrapper. 
If the object ever goes out of scope (e.g. by `Set AppSettings = Nothing`) the attributes get auto-repopulated when the default instance is respawned.

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
' AppSettings is a stateful default instance singleton class
' Prevent additional instance creation with "New"

    If Not Me Is AppSettings Then
        Err.Raise _
            vbObjectError + 1024, _
            "Invalid Object Instance", _
            TypeName(Me) & ": New is not permitted on Static Classes"
    End If

    'Call BootStrapper procedure to auto-initialise properties
    BootStrapper

End Sub
```

Comment: Seems somewhat opinion-based. If it solves your problem, why worry about what others might think? If you were to worry about that, then you would stop using VBA (which has been the "most hated" programming language on the Stack Overflow developer's survey for 2 years in a row). As far as other ideas go, you could (assuming this is Excel) store persistent information in the workbook's `Names` collection or use [custom properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.customproperties)

Comment: You could use document properties to hold these values and read them from inside `Private Property Get` statements. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/property-get-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of Class with a PredeclaredId to store state is fully acceptable provided it is the only instance of the class.  One way to ensure this is to use to Class_Initialize sub to test that the current instance is the PredeclaredId and to error out if it is not (i.e. some tried to new the class with the PredecalredId.

e.g for a class called PersistentData

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    If Not Me Is PersistentData Then

        Err.Raise _
            vbObjectError + 17, _
            "Invalid New", _
             TypeName(Me) & ": New is not permitted on Static Classes"

    End If

    'Add other class specific initialisation here

End Sub
```

A good point to remember is that the Class_Initialize sub will run the first time that PersistentData is encountered in an expression.  This action can be used to 'auto' initialize a class.

You should also be advised that the excellent Rubberduck addin for VBA provides annotations which allow a PredeclaredId to be set from within the code itself rather than manually setting after exporting the code to a text editor.

There are also other options for storing such data such as Document variables, custom document properties, and customxml.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for a way to prevent newing up of the class and that works nicely. I've been using Rubberduck for a few weeks now - you're right, it's an excellent tool.